# Checking paths in bash

Tags: bash

I am writing a program checking each directory from the user's path and making sure it exists and is readable.

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=: read -ra dirs <<< "$PATH"

for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; 
do
if [[ -d "$dir" ]] && [[ -r "$dir" ]] 
then
echo "Directory $dir exists and is readable"
else
echo "Directory $dir does not exist or is not readable"
fi
done
```

I feel like I am close however, when I run the program I get the error a conditional binary operator expected in line 8 and it is referring to the -r I believe.

Comment: I think it should be `[[ -d "$dir" && -r "$dir" ]]`. Not entirely sure

Comment: learn to paste your code at https://shellcheck.net and use any recommendations. Be sure to include `#!/bin/bash` (or whatever shell you want checked) as the first line of code. Good luck.

Comment: you may want to ensure the directory has the correct "execution" bit set, `-x "$dir"`. Good luck.

Comment: I am able to run your code as-is. Also a note about putting `&&` inside the `[[ ]]` - For bash `[[ ]]` operator, you CAN put the `&&` inside the brackets; but having 2 separate conditions like in your code is also perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Your code works like a charm here with bash 5.2.9.

Comment: The code in the question works fine with Bash 4 and Bash 3 too.  Maybe one of the characters in your file containing the code is not what it appears to be.  Document editors (not code editors) sometimes convert typed dash/hyphen characters to Unicode dash characters.  The converted dashes don't work in Bash test operators.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

IFS=: read -ra dirs <<< "$PATH"

for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; 
do
if [[ -d "$dir" && -r "$dir" ]] 
then
echo "Directory $dir exists and is readable"
else
echo "Directory $dir does not exist or is not readable"
fi
done
```

this will work

Comment: Can you explain?